# Persist node_modules with local docker volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Goal: I want to use Docker to develop React and Express locally. I have two services in `docker-compose.yaml` with the folders (`node_modules`) that I want to persist local changes.

```
  client:
    container_name: web
    volumes:
      - ./client/:/app
      - ./.env:/app/.env
      - client_node_modules:/app/node_modules

  server:
    container_name: server
    volumes:
      - ./server/:/app
      - ./.env:/app/.env
      - server_node_modules:/app/node_modules

volumes:
  client_node_modules:
    external: true
  server_node_modules:
    external: true
```

I ran the docker command to create the two new volumes: `client_node_modules && server_node_modules` but when I am in the client directory and remove the axios dependency it still calls the service.

In the Dockerfile we do have `COPY ./package.json ./` so maybe that's not persistent? Am I doing this at all right? How can i achieve my goal?

Comment: What benefits are you hoping to get from Docker here, over doing development with a copy of Node installed on your host?

Comment: @DavidMaze, I may be wrong here! My goal is to have a Docker file for dev and another one for production. For me this is apart of the learning experience and I may be over complicating life but for example I have one use case where I need a reverse proxy in nginx so my frontend can call my backend which is running on a different port.